# Making sure a block of code is executed after async function

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I'm creating an app using Firestore, I have a function that supposed to add a user to another user's friends list and return true if it was done successfully.
This is the function:

```
static func addFriendToList(_ id: String) -> Bool {

    var friend: Friend!
    var isSuccessfullyAddedFriend: Bool = false
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        group.enter()
        // Getting user's deatils and creating a Friend object.
        FirestoreService.shared.getUserDetailsById(user: id) { (newFriend) in
            if newFriend != nil {
                friend = newFriend!
            }
            group.leave()
        }
        group.wait()

        group.enter()
        // Adding the new Friend Object to the friends list of the current user
        FirestoreService.shared.addUserToFriendsList(friend: friend) { (friendAdded) in
            if friendAdded {
                isSuccessfullyAddedFriend = true
                FirestoreService.shared.fetchFriendList()
            }
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.wait()
    return isSuccessfullyAddedFriend
}
```

My problem is that the `addUserToFriendsList` is an async function, and the `return` `isSuccessfullyAddedFriend` is being executed before it turns to `true`.
As you can see, I tried to overcome this problem with using DispatchGroup, but with no success, the problem still occurs. Is there another, maybe better way to achieve this?
I need the `return` line to happen after `addUserToFriendsList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
static func addFriendToList(_ id: String,completion:@escaping(Bool)->()) { 

        FirestoreService.shared.getUserDetailsById(user: id) { (newFriend) in

            FirestoreService.shared.addUserToFriendsList(friend: newFriend) { (friendAdded) in
                if friendAdded { 
                     FirestoreService.shared.fetchFriendList()
                     completion(true)
                }
                else {
                     completion(false)
                }

            }
        } 

}
```

---

Call

```
Api.addFriendToList(<#id#>) { flag in
  print(flag)
}
```

---

2 notes

1- Firebase calls run in a background thread so no need for global queue

2- DispatchGroup is used for multiple concurrent tasks not serial

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. It is still interesting though, is there a way to execute a line after only after async is finished?

Comment: Thanks about the notes. I didn't know that about the Firebase calls, that's good to know. and about the DispatchGroup, I also didn't know, I will be sure to learn more about it and it's uses. Thank you!